# MYSQL8 unknown runaway memory

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

First thank you, I am not very knowledgeable in MYSQL and am purely self taught.

I moved from metal to AWS(EC2, with maxed out IOPS:3000) and in the process we also upgrade from MYSQL5.6 to MYSQL8.0.28.

We have had major memory issues with MYSQL8 and cannot seem to track it down.
It takes several days (~5-10) to exhaust memory on our production server (~1k requests per second) MYSQL is takes up over 100% of our 16GB of memory.

It slowly creeps up with a few random spikes.

we have 16GB of memory, the old metal server also had 16GB.

all tables are innodb.

I reduced innodb_buffer_pool_size from 8GB to 4GB to try and stabilize the server with no joy.

any advise would be a lot of help for me to understand what is going on.

---

## UPDATE 4-25-2022

I wanted to let this run for a few days to let it get back to an add state. I changed a bunch of settings based on another post recommendation, so i removed the previous information for this thread.

mysqlc.cnf
https://pastebin.com/FRuh55Lx

The paste bins request by Wilson below:

A)439

B) https://pastebin.com/86Tj6YBe

C) https://pastebin.com/Jn19dyu7

D)

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+-------+---------+--------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| Id      | User            | Host                 | db    | Command | Time   | State                  | Info                  |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+-------+---------+--------+------------------------+-----------------------+
|       5 | event_scheduler | localhost            | NULL  | Daemon  | 357369 | Waiting on empty queue | NULL                  |
| 2208882 | root            | localhost            | NULL  | Sleep   |    330 |                        | NULL                  |
| 2210947 | root            | localhost            | NULL  | Sleep   |    144 |                        | NULL                  |
| 2211462 | calypso         | <removed>:33362 |  <removed>| Sleep   |     52 |                        | NULL                  |
| 2211998 | freeradius      | localhost            |  <removed>| Sleep   |      0 |                        | NULL                  |
| 2212151 | calypso         |  <removed>:33992 |  <removed>| Sleep   |     52 |                        | NULL                  |
| 2212502 | freeradius      | localhost            | ikeja | Sleep   |      0 |                        | NULL                  |
| 2212641 | root            | localhost            | NULL  | Query   |      0 | init                   | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+-------+---------+--------+------------------------+-----------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

E)

```
mysql> STATUS;
--------------
mysql  Ver 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Connection id:          2212641
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Binary data as:         Hexadecimal
Uptime:                 4 days 3 hours 18 min 15 sec

Threads: 12  Questions: 37878605  Slow queries: 35  Opens: 1647  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 1501  Queries per second avg: 105.955
--------------
```

Comment: See if [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62021/mysql-not-releasing-memory) helps.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
AWS type in use? Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: "takes up over 100% of our 16GB" -- did swapping occur?

Comment: Perhaps you meant "MySQL 8.0.20"?

Comment: With those settings, MySQL should never fill up RAM.  What was running at the spike?  Use `pt-query-digest` to analyze the slowlog.  Also, I'll analyze at the STATUS(etc) when you provide it for Wilson.

Comment: It had a little spike today, so i got an update. Thank you guys so much! Let me know if you need more information.